# ASP.NET customErrors show as pure HTML in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Error.htm" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="/Error401.htm"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error403.htm"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error404.htm"/>
      (...)
</customErrors>
```

It works well under IE 8 and Firefox 3.6, but fails under Google Chrome 7.

You can test with this link: http://www.buzzmath.com/this_page_does_not_exist.aspx

Any ideas?
Carl

Comment: What is the "pure html" that is being shown in Chrome?

Comment: @mlms13: To test, you can use this link:

http://www.buzzmath.com/this_page_does_not_exist.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Content-Type is set in the Response and Chrome defaults it to text while Firefox and IE render it as HTML.

Try setting the Content-Type to text/html.

Also you should validate your page, it seems to have quite a few problems which results in this "wierd" behavior.

Comment: Pages were validated with the w3c validator. I'll double check thanks.

Comment: IIS should set this, I'll search why it did not put any Content-Type this week, thanks.

Comment: @Malartre: Have you gotten to the root cause of this problem, i.e. why IIS doesn't set the Content-Type for the .htm files?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue. resolved by change `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` to `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"`